# Cocos 2d. How can I add the cursor in the TextField?

Tags: user-interface, cursor, cocos2d-x, textfield, cocos2d-js

In Cocos Studio I created my UI, but my TextField without a cursor. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem to be currently supported at the moment: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/issues/12044#issuecomment-132053053

*Support cursor and other fancy editbox feature on top of OpenGL is tricky.
So we decide to drop TextField and put all of our effort into improving the EditBox control*

I recommend you check out `EditBox`.

Comment: Oh flip! After spending so much time making TextField into something more like what you find on web forms it is now going to be dropped. Better go check out EditBox.

Comment: It's awful. When I add the EditBox to the panel, which was created in CocosStudio, all other elements are collected in a corner of the panel. I'll have to add a separate layer to the scene for the EditBox.

Comment: I could add EditBox directly replacing the TextField in the panel._сhildren. Also pointing EditBox._parent - panel.